# Load raw data into array as strings

Tags: python, arrays, text-files

So I understand how to manipulate a text file and move data in and out of the program, but I'm trying to take raw data in a text file, and load them into an array that is originally empty, how would I make this approach?

Assume my raw data contains 3 words, I want to place those words into a variable called `Array`. The raw data of the text file contains the 3 following words: `' Apple Banana Orange '`. I would like it to load into the array as: `Array = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]`. How would you approach this?

```
with open("C:\\Users\\NameList.txt","r") as f:
    Array = []
    nameList = f.readlines(Array)
```

Am aware the code is wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix even after reading so much.

Comment: import numpy as np
my_list = [2,4,6,8,10]
my_array = np.array(my_list)
# printing my_array
print my_array
# printing the type of my_array
print type(my_array) copied from https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-convert-a-list-to-an-array-in-python

Comment: @pippo1980 I guess, the OP uses array as a synonym of `list`, they are not referring to a numpy array.

Comment: `Array = open("C:\\Users\\NameList.txt", "r").readlines()` ?

Comment: One word per line or all words in one line? If first then use `Array = f.readlines()`.

Comment: from text is r all words in one line: The raw data of the text file contains the 3 following words: ' Apple Banana Orange '

Answer (score 1):

If your input `test.txt` is like below:

> Apple Banana Orange

This is the solution you are looking for.

```
with open("test.txt","r")as f:
    text = f.readlines()
    Array = text[0].split()
```

In case you have more than 1 line, you can use this one:

```
with open("test.txt","r")as f:
    text = f.read().splitlines()
    Array = [i.split() for i in text]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will read all the lines in your file:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\NameList.txt","r")as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
Array = list()

for line in lines:
    Array.append(line)
print(Array)

for item in Array:
    if 'Apple' == item:
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
#first loop
['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange']
#second loop
Apple
```

Comment: Ok, and they are listed as strings? because i would like to be able to access each individual as a string, and if i run a condition to confirm a variable like name = "Apple" and find out if its in the array, it doesnt seem to detect it

Comment: dont know the way to set array type in array but there should be one

Comment: They are string, you can use a `print(type(item))` to check the type, I edited the code for what you need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882019/can-i-store-strings-in-python-array ; Can I store strings in python array try

Comment: does:  'Array = Array.tounicode()' works ? see : https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.htmlhttps://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html

Comment: @ExoticLegend714 the condition didn't work at first because it was storing a white-space at the end of  ` 'Apple'` so what you were comparing was `'Apple' == 'Apple '`, This could happened because of a whitespace at the end of 'Apple' in your file